# Is there any way to get rid of npm optional dependency warnings through editing package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, warnings, fsevents

I hate warnings.

Especially when those warnings are completely ignorable.

Most warnings I encounter are non-clean code warnings and I like to have my code clean. Other warning are actual errors.

Sometimes I miss error warnings because they were "hidden" between other warnings.

So I like to keep things clean.

Thus when I do `npm install` and see this:

```
[folatt@MyComputer ~]$ npm install
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

up to date in 33.232s
```

I want to get rid of that warning.

I know of the `--no-optional` argument, but that seems hacky to me as well.
Isn't there anything one can do in package.json to get rid of this warning?

Comment: I am having the exact same warning for ages now - would really appreciate a way on how to get rid of these.

Comment: +1 here - struggling with this. I know that npm i -f works. But I don't want to use this. I just want to remove all fsevents warnings...

Comment: This has not yet been released by npm. Reference: https://github.com/npm/cli/pull/169#issuecomment-667304732

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in npm v7. If you update your npm, you shouldn't see these unactionable warnings anymore.

On [this GitHub question](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1112), someone confirmed that the fsevents skipping optional dependency warnings have been removed in npm v7:

> Yep, it’s fixed in v7.

<sup>([source](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1112#issuecomment-667315316))</sup>

Answer (score -3):

You should be able to silence those messages with environment values.

```
npm_config_loglevel=silent
```

> Default: “notice”

> Values: “silent”, “error”, “warn”, “notice”, “http”,
> “timing”, “info”, “verbose”, “silly”

Details here;
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel

Comment: But that will silence all other warnings and messages too.

Comment: @OrangeDog unfortunately yes. But it doesn't have to be silent of course. Setting to "error" will still provide sufficient messages. I don't see any other way for this case.

Answer (score -6):

You can use `npm audit fix` command.
Also if you could share your `package.json` file that will be helpful

Comment: No, that has no effect on these warnings, which happen on a PC because the optional dependency is for Apple stuff.

Comment: ```npm audit fix``` is used for a different thing. It will fix possible security vulnerabilities. The question is about optional dependencies warnings during installation.