# I am getting Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4 error while installing Angular. How to solve it?

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, node-modules

> C:\Users\vivek>npm install -g @angular/cli
>   C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng ->
>   C:\Users\vivek\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4
>   (node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup
>   SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4:
>   wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
>   {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> - @angular/cli@7.0.6 added 265 packages from 205 contributors in 131.235s
>
> C:\Users\vivek>node -v v11.1.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get rid of npm optional dependency warnings through editing package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940423/is-there-any-way-to-get-rid-of-npm-optional-dependency-warnings-through-editing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning will appear if you are working in WINDOWS OS.
fsevents npm library will be supported in MAC OS only.

This is just a warning. You can ignore it.