# Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2 installation issue

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, chokidar, next-pwa

I've been trying to deploy my application to vercel for a while now and have been reading through  lots of posts here on stackoverflow with the the same/similar `fsevents` issue. Despite everything I keep getting the same errors posted below.

things I've tried:

- uninstall `node_modules` & `package-lock.json`, then running: `npm i -f`
- adding   `"optionalDependencies": {"fsevents": "^2.3.2"}`, then `npm i -f`
- installing with no `fsevents` in `package.json`
- ... and many other attempts

#### Screen shot of what always happens in my deploys

I'm not super familiar with that what/why of the whole fsevents/chokidar packages, but it seems like it's needed for my MacOS after what I've been reading and I'd really appreciate some ideas for resolving this.

[image]

#### current package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix ."
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^8.2.5",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.13.1",
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2",
    "js-cookies": "^1.0.4",
    "next": "10.0.6",
    "next-pwa": "^5.0.5",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.2.1"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "^2.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.14.25",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.7",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-nextjs": "^1.0.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^5.0.5",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.7.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.3",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.21.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Kevin, just today I've stumbled upon the same problem. Have you made any progress? In my case, when I add fsevents=2.3.2 to optionalDependencies, my AWS codebuild throws an error when trying to install yet an older version of fsevents. I'm feeling played...

Comment: Hey Kevin, it seems my AWS codebuild container had some old packages cached. I fixed the issue by appending a forcing npm to install all packages from remote with the -f option

Comment: @Sebastian hello, i think I tried forcing the installation in the past as well and if i remember correctly it didn't work. Though, if it worked for you I may need to re-explore that option. Thanks for the update! :)

Comment: The same problem for Microsoft Azure, I don't know why the cloud providers uses old runtimes, yet Azure hasn't support NodeJS 15 runtime

Comment: Similar: npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64... npm i -f doesn't help

Comment: I got the same error deploying a MERN app to render.com. I guess it was a compatibility issue between package-lock.json and package.json. Run npm ci ,after that run npm audit fix. 
npm ci ensures that you have the exact dependencies and versions listed in the package-lock.json file. That did it for me.

Answer (score 18):

lots of people complaining about this going back years.

sometimes the fix is upgrading to newer npm.  (running npm 7.7 and still had it)

often the fix is just :

```
npm install -f
```

so forcing it worked just fine here.

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem because at the team we had different os types `Linux/MacOS/Windows`
I manually edited the `package-lock.json` and added the different os types

```
"node_modules/fsevents": {
  ...
  "os": [
        "darwin",
        "win32",
        "linux"
      ],
  ...
}
```

after that, I ran `npm install`

Comment: As awful as it is this is the only thing which solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is getting these errors on an old version of Node / npm, the best option is likely to upgrade.

```
node --version
```

If (as of 2023) this outputs something less than 16.x you probably need to upgrade.

Install / update node to the latest LTS release: https://nodejs.org/en/download and these errors should be fixed.