# React npm start not working : 'No version of chokidar available'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, chokidar

I cloned my already working React-Typescript app on Github Pages, from Github and wanted to make some changes. I ran npm install and installed all the dependencies but when I run npm start, I got this error;

[image]

I don't know what chokidar is and I looked a little bit and I think it's unrelated to my project. Still I tried to npm install chokidar and I got another error like this;

[image]

Also tried `npm audit fix` as well. Fixed some stuff but nothing changed.

So I can't open the development server. Additionally, this is the package.json file;

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "panflix",
  "homepage": "https://absolutezero13.github.io/meerkast/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/redux-devtools": "^3.0.47",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "firebase": "^8.2.7",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7"
  }
}
```

I tried `npm install -g chokidar` and it is installed. But I'm getting the same error as before "no version chokidar is available."

Other react projects are working fine.

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/56105431/9095807

Answer (score 37):

I had the same issue. What worked for me is forcing updates on local npm packages:

```
npm update --force
```

#### Before

```
$ npm list chokidar
pwa-react-showcase@0.1.0
└─┬ react-scripts@4.0.3
  └─┬ webpack-dev-server@3.11.1
    └── chokidar@2.1.8
```

#### After

```
$ npm list chokidar
pwa-react-showcase@0.1.0
└─┬ react-scripts@4.0.3
  ├─┬ webpack-dev-server@3.11.1
  │ └── chokidar@2.1.8
  └─┬ webpack@4.44.2
    └─┬ watchpack@1.7.5
      ├── chokidar@3.5.1
      └─┬ watchpack-chokidar2@2.0.1
        └── chokidar@2.1.8
```

#### Update

We found that NPM 7 was the issue. Downgrading to NPM 6.14.12 works without any changes.

Comment: Downgrading works, but there is no need. You can just npm update chokidar. See my answer below. Also force update might not be a good idea to update all the dependencies if you have not specified the exact version of the dependency.

Answer (score 32):

Just solved my issue by running

`npm update chokidar`

This will update the package-lock.json with latest chokidar info. Now running react without any issues with npm 7.15 and node 14.16. There is no need to force install or do anything quirky. Just update chokidar to keep your package files consistent and keep development running for everyone in the team.

Original problem came up when I updated from NPM 6 to version 7. There is also a bug ticket in github: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10811

Comment: This solution is the simplest working for me so far, thanks! Resolve the exact same issue on a CRA app just updated to npm 7.

Comment: This solution solved all of my issues, thank you!

Answer (score 17):

The same problem occurred to me after upgrading from `npm@6.x` to `npm@7.x`. I solved my problem with simply installing `chokidar` as a `DevDependency`. Everything works as expected (development, production build and tests)

For more assurance run:

```
npm i -g npm
npm cache verify
npm i -D chokidar
npm i
```

Comment: It seems to be enough to just update chokidar with npm update chokidar. One command needed at least for me =)

Comment: That is nice. Does it work with pure clone? e.g. `rm -rf node_modules; npm i ; npm start` ?

Comment: probably not if you have not updated you package-lock file. Then just `rm -rf node_modules; npm i ; npm update chokidar; npm start`

Comment: Aha. nice. I just asked to make sure other teammates would then be able to benefit just from a simple `npm i`

Comment: Your teammates can just npm i if you first update the package lock file and push it to the repository for everybody.

Answer (score 5):

Chockidar is a dependency inside watchpak which takes care of hot reloads on save on development environment.

Chuckidar 2 has problems with node v14+.

For me, `npm update` did update watchpack to use chockidar 3.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the version of chokidar NEEDS to be updated to 3

Method 1:

> **npm i chokidar@latest --force**

This worked for me.
npm itself says : *npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.*

---

Method 2(Recommended):

> **npm audit fix**

If you are connecting via proxy on company network this might not work for you and you could get something like this:

**npm ERR! audit endpoint returned an error**

---

Method 3:

- **Downgrade npm version to 6**

---

Method 4:

> **npm update --force**

Would not recommended for large projects.

Answer (score 3):

Updating Chokidar dependency solved the problem for me.

`npm update chokidar`

Answer (score 3):

You needs to update chokidar. So simply needs to hit the command
`npm update chokidar`
OR
`npm update chokidar@2`

if you gets error like as
`invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/chokidar reason: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Then main reason for it may be cache, so you have to clean cache. For that, hit the command
`npm cache clean --force`

After this, if you again gets one more error like as

```
 `ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'`
```

Then you needs to rebuild node sass, by hitting the command
`npm rebuild node-sass`

That's all, how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This command will fix your problem :

```
$ npm update chokidar
```

I got this problem also when I'm cloning project and installing npm

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem today
I search everywhere, and then fix my problem with this:

**$ npm update --force**

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Centos7 and my Chokidar version is "^3.5.3".

My issue was resolved by running this command:

`npm update --force`