# Node v20.5.1 Zoom React meeting sample error - digital envelope routines::unsupported ... ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED

Tags: node.js, webpack, zoom-sdk

Trying to get the [zoom react meetingsdk sample](https://github.com/zoom/meetingsdk-react-sample) working, and when I run npm start I get the following error:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported....

  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
```

[image: ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED digital envelope routines error]

I've tried to use the responses from [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-js-17-0-1-gatsby-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported-err-os), setting node options to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "set SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

And downgrading node versions from v20.5.1 to multiple earlier versions 18.xx, 19.xx

But npm start always spits out that error message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved this issue. It was related to openssl-legacy-provider, and the solution was a modified version from [this stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69665222/node-js-17-0-1-gatsby-error-digital-envelope-routinesunsupported-err-os)

essentially, was using windows so tried the top answer, changing package.json scripts to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "set SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

However, "set SET NODE_OPTIONS....." did not work, instead tweaking this to:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts start",
    "build": "SET NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && react-scripts build"
}
```

Resolved the issues.

A cleaner implementation of the above:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"
}
```

The meetingsdk had some further issues to overcome, such as 'No version of chokidar available' ( [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66734503/react-npm-start-not-working-no-version-of-chokidar-available) )