# Error in installing pcf-scripts using npm i

Tags: node.js, npm, powerapps-component-framework

There is an error when I tried to upgrade my installed pcf-scripts by invoking `npm i pcf-scripts@1.7.2`. My current pcf-scripts version is 1.5.5. The error is

```
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Comment: This is explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103865/how-to-fix-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents1-2-9-wanted-osdarwin-arch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103865/how-to-fix-unsupported-platform-for-fsevents1-2-9-wanted-osdarwin-arch)