# Unable to remove npm warn message while running angular application

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm

I need one help. I need to remove the `npm warn` message while I am trying to do the `npm install` through dockerfile. I am explaining those warning message below.

while running `RUN npm install --no-package-lock` getting the following warn message.

```
npm WARN deprecated @angular/http@7.2.16: Package no longer supported. Use @angular/common instead, see https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated ag-grid@18.1.2: ag-grid is now deprecated - please use @ag-grid-community/all-modules. See www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-modules/ for more information.
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.2: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated ini@1.3.5: Please update to ini >=1.3.6 to avoid a prototype pollution issue
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.0.4: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated clipboard-js@0.3.6: Please migrate to https://github.com/lgarron/clipboard-polyfill
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
```

and while running `RUN npm install` then getting the following warnings.

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@2.1.2: "Please update to latest v2.3 or v2.2"
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @auth0/angular-jwt@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=9.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng-file-drop@5.0.2 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So here I need to remove these warnings while running those command through dockerfile. I also tried many options by searching from google but those did not give the right solutions. Can any body help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get rid of npm optional dependency warnings through editing package.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940423/is-there-any-way-to-get-rid-of-npm-optional-dependency-warnings-through-editing)

Comment: I have tried but that did not work.